# why is my "at job" not executing my php script when created through a php webpage?

Tags: php, apache, centos7

```
$output = shell_exec('echo "php '.$realFile.'" | at '.$targTime.' '.$targDate.' 2>&1');
print $output;
```

Can someone please help me figure out why the above line isn't doing what it's supposed to be doing? The idea is for it to create an 'at' job that will execute a php script. If I switch to the user apache(which will ideally control the at function when the php file is complete) I can run

```
echo "php $realFile.php" | at 00:00 05/30/17
```

and it'll do EXACTLY what I want. The problem is in the above snippet from my php file it will not create the at job correctly. when I do a `at -c job#` on both of them the job made from my file is about a 3rd the length missing the User info and everything. It basically starts at PATH= and goes down. Doesn't include HOSTNAME=, SHELL=, SSH_CLIENT=, SSH_TTY=, USER=. I assume it needs most of this info to run correctly. The end output (below)is always the same though it just doesn't have any of the top part for some reason. Let me know if you need more info. I didn't want to paste all of my code here as it contains job specific information.

```
${SHELL:-/bin/sh} << 'marcinDELIMITER0e4bb3e8'
php "$realFile".php

marcinDELIMITER0e4bb3e8
```

It doesn't seem to be a permission issue because I can su to apache and run the exact command needed. The folder the files are located in are also owned by apache. I've also resulted to giving each file I try to run 777 or 755 permissions through chmod so I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a coupe ways around it a while back. The way I'm using right now is an ssh2 connect to my own server as root and creating it that way. No compromise as you have to enter the password manually each time. Really bad work around. The main issue is that apache doesn't have the correct permissions to do everything needed for the AT job so someone figuring that out would be awesome. Another option I found on a random webpage would be to use sudo through the php script, but basically the same minus having to reconnect to your own server. Any other options would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the manual and logs would be a good place to start. In particular:

> The  value  of  the  SHELL environment variable at the time of at invocation will determine which shell is used to execute the at job commands. If SHELL is unset when at is invoked, the user’s login shell will be used; otherwise, if SHELL is set when at  is  invoked, it must contain the path of a shell interpreter executable that will be used to run the commands at the specified time.

Other things to check are that the user is included in at.allow, SELinux is disabled and the webserver is not running chrrot.

Comment: Ok so it's saying that the at job won't make the php run because it's using the incorrect shell because it wasn't created as root? Is that correct? If so how do I get around that?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that this excerpt from the man page might be the reason your code is not working as you expect. You can't test what the value of SHELL is within a script (because it's not getting executed by atd) but you might try explicitly `putenv("SHELL=/bin/hash") && $output = shell_exec('echo "php '.$realFile.'" | at '.$targTime.' '.$targDate.' 2>&1');`

Comment: Ok I went ahead and added that. I also added the USER= after that didn't work and still nothing. It did update the at job info but does not execute the php script.